# How to support different Android versions?

Tags: android, api, version

I found that from API 19+ their is a small change in code and it doesn't appear in API 19-.
How can I support both android versions in the same app?

EDIT: The are feature that exists only in android 4.1.2 and in versions below 4.1.2 they doesn't exists.

How can I make an app that support both versions with the exception that in lower version the "new" features won't exist? (its hard for me to explain)

Comment: Please be more precise asking.

Comment: Well... 19+ 19- = 0!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the API 19-specific code inside a conditional that queries the device version with the enumerated values present in Build.VERSION_CODES.

for instance :

```
if ( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT )
{
    // Kitkat (API level 19) code in here...
}
else {
    // code for all versions lower than Kitkat in here...
}
```